# jQuery animation PushX moves fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a template that makes use of Javascript and jQuery to turn the navigation bar into a toggle-able pane that slides in and out from the left hand side. Everything on my site works well with it except for a fixed div that is fixed to the bottom of the page. It always moves up to the level of the lowest list item in the navigation bar.

The relevant JS code is:

```js
//Javascript that controls the nav bar once the screen reaches a small size

plugins: {
 layers: {
  config: {
   mode: 'transform'
  },
  navPanel: {
   animation: 'pushX',
   breakpoints: 'medium',
   clickToHide: true,    
            height: '100%',
   hidden: true,
   html: '<div data-action="moveElement" data-args="nav"></div>',
            orientation: 'vertical',
   position: 'top-left',
   side: 'left',
   width: 250
  },
  navButton: {
   breakpoints: 'medium',
   height: '4em',
   html: '<span class="toggle" data-action="toggleLayer" data-args="navPanel"></span>',
   position: 'top-left',
   side: 'top',
   width: '6em'
  }
 }
}
```

```css
//CSS for the bar that moves undesireably

#button_bar {
 position: fixed !important;
 bottom: 0 !important;
 background-color: #303030;
 z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

```css
//Computed CSS for the bottom div (button_bar)

background-color
#303030
border-bottom-color
#444
border-bottom-style
none
border-bottom-width
0px
border-image-outset
0 0 0 0
border-image-repeat
stretch stretch
border-image-slice
100% 100% 100% 100%
border-image-source
none
border-image-width
1 1 1 1
border-left-color
#444
border-left-style
none
border-left-width
0px
border-right-color
#444
border-right-style
none
border-right-width
0px
border-top-color
#444
border-top-style
none
border-top-width
0px
bottom
0px

inline:204
#button_bar0px
box-sizing
border-box
color
#444
font-family
"Lato",Helvetica,sans-serif
font-feature-settings
normal
font-kerning
auto
font-language-override
normal
font-size
16px
font-size-adjust
none
font-stretch
normal
font-style
normal
font-synthesis
weight style
font-variant
normal
font-variant-alternates
normal
font-variant-caps
normal
font-variant-east-asian
normal
font-variant-ligatures
normal
font-variant-numeric
normal
font-variant-position
normal
font-weight
300
line-height
26.4px
margin-bottom
0px
margin-left
0px
margin-right
0px
margin-top
0px
padding-bottom
0px
padding-left
0px
padding-right
0px
padding-top
0px
position
fixed
vertical-align
baseline
width
823px
z-index
10
-moz-border-bottom-colors
none
-moz-border-left-colors
none
-moz-border-right-colors
none
-moz-border-top-colors
none
```

[Before, desirable layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVrbP.png)
[After, undesirable div movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgXh6.png)

Comment: What's the computed css of the bottom div

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the response.
I have used the developer tools in Firefox to find the computed css of the bottom div and added it to my question. I hope this is what you are asking for, otherwise could you explain what you mean by computed css a little further? Thanks!
The computed CSS appears not to change when toggling the nav bar in and out.

Comment: Where is the position of the div in the page. Is it "inside" the popout menu when it bugs?

Comment: It is not inside the popout menu but it does become a child of a div created by javascript layout functions. Now that I know to look out for that I will do some more tracing to find the root of the issue.
I have changed the animation to "fade" and it works perfectly so I may just leave it like that.